# Convert response string possibly to utf16

Tags: iphone, encoding, utf

Hello
I am getting a response string from server this string:Kav\u00e1la.
After a search on google this "\u00e1" is UTF16.
I am trying to convert it using this:

```
NSString *myJson = [responseString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

but nothing. Its the same

Answer (score 0):

"\u00e1" is the character "á" (lowercase a-acute).